# Autotools adds library flags to ar

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, autotools

I'm currently porting my C++ project to use the GNU autotools toolchain, and I'm having trouble setting up my library dependencies. What seems to be happening is that it gives the command `ar` flags meant for g++, such as `-lSDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2_image -lSDL2`.

Here's the code for `src/Makefile.am`:

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libccade.a
libccade_a_SOURCES = CCade.h CCade_graphics.h CCade_graphics.cpp CCade_util.h CCade_util.cpp
libccade_a_LIBADD = $(libsdl2_LIBS) $(libsdl2_image_LIBS)
libccade_a_CFLAGS = $(libsdl2_CFLAGS) $(libsdl2_image_CFLAGS)
```

Here's what `make` puts out:

```
ar cru libccade.a CCade_graphics.o CCade_util.o -lSDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2_image -lSDL2
ar: invalid option -- 'L'
Usage: ar [emulation options] [-]{dmpqrstx}[abcDfilMNoPsSTuvV] [--plugin <name>] [member-name] [count] archive-file file...
...(more documentation on ar)...
```

It seems to be adding the args from `libccade_a_LIBADD`, but if I remove that variable, then it wouldn't give the flags to `g++`. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not using `libtool`. What I generally do is put this in my `configure.ac`:

```
AM_PROG_LIBTOOL
```

And then my `Makefile.am` would be something like:

```
noinst_HEADERS = CCade.h CCade_graphics.h CCade_util.h

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libccade.la

libccade_la_SOURCES = CCade_graphics.cpp CCade_util.cpp
libccade_la_LIBADD = $(libsdl2_LIBS) $(libsdl2_image_LIBS)
libccade_la_CPPFLAGS = $(libsdl2_CFLAGS) $(libsdl2_image_CFLAGS)
```

Making sure that the second variable is *noinst_**LT**LIBRARIES*, it should work for you.

Comment: I tried following your solution, and while I do believe I'm a step closer, I still get the same error.

Comment: @MathManiac Did you **replace** your code with my code or is your code still in there?

Comment: *EDIT:* Wait.. I realized that you added "LT" on the second variable. Changing that now..

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect this line to do?:

```
libccade_a_LIBADD = $(libsdl2_LIBS) $(libsdl2_image_LIBS)
```

ar doesn't do any linking, it doesn't care about other libraries, so there's no need to specify them here.